# How to hide the tool tip when mouse is out of the control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi all i have written a code for `Jquery` in which both `Click & Hover` functions will work for the same control which works fine. But when i `hover` my mouse on a control tool tip showing fine, but if i move my mouse out of the control tool tip remains as it is so can any one tell me where should i change.

This is what i written

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function() 
{      
$('#foobar9').bind('mouseover click',function(e) {        
if(e.type == 'click'){         
var close = true        
} 
else 
{        
var close = false        
}        
var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
$(this).formBubble({
url: url,         
dataType: 'html',         
cache: false,       
closeButton: close       });       
return false;     });
}); 
</script>
```

The reference site is http://lyconic.com/resources/tools/formbubble

As per the given answer i tried this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function() 
{      
$('#A1').bind('mouseover mouseout click',function(e) {        

if(e.type=='mouseout')
{
          $.fn.formBubble.close(thisBubble);
}

if(e.type == 'click'){         // do some click event stuff         
var close = true        
}
else 
{         // do some hover event stuff         
var close = false        
}        
var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
$(this).formBubble({
url: url,         
dataType: 'html',         
cache: false,       
closeButton: close       });       
return false;     });
}); 
</script>

<div>
    <a href="ajaxtest/index10.html" class="ohhai-world" id="A1">HTML-based AJAX (Click)</a>
</div>
```

Comment: dont you forgot to use the mouseout ?

Comment: Hey thats what i was confused where to write that

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hiding-title-and-alt-tooltips

Comment: did you try onmouseout event?

Comment: `ric_bfa` didn't get you

Comment: try to put the $(this).formBubble({..}); before the if(e.type=='mouseout'){..}

Comment: Required Tool tip is not showing if i use as per the given

Comment: updated my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

try to use `delegate()` or just do the `mouseout()` event.

```
$('#foobar9').delegate('body','mouseover mouseout click',function(e) {        
  if(e.type === 'click'){         
      // ...      
  }else if(e.type === 'mouseover'){
      // ...
  }else if(e.type === 'mouseout'){
      //...
  }
});
```

**Edit:**

i try  something here, and works for me, check this:

**html:**

```
    <a href="#" id="A1">Static Text (Hover)</a>
```

**js:**

```
    $('#A1').bind('mouseover mouseout', function(e) { //hover
        if(e.type == "mouseover"){
            $(this).formBubble({
                closeButton: false
            });
            $.fn.formBubble.text('hover hover hover hover');
        }
        if(e.type == "mouseout"){
            var thisBubble = $.fn.formBubble.bubbleObject;
            $.fn.formBubble.close(thisBubble);
        }
    });
```

**js click:**

```
 $('#A1').bind('click', function(e) { //hover
        $(this).formBubble({
            alignment: {
            bubble: 'left',
            pointer: 'top-right'
          },
          text: 'text'
        });
      return false;
  });
```

Comment: in mouse over what should i write can you tell i have written the exact as per in the link but didn't work for me

Comment: found this: $.fn.formBubble.close(); try using this on the mouseout.

Comment: strange, try to debug, use the pluging as default in a separated page to see if works.

Comment: How about click event in the same. When i click on that i would like to show the tool tip too

Comment: you wanna use a click with mouseover ? but when u hover to click, the hover event will fire first and the tooltip will apear.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

```
http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/
```